# systemd-sysv-generator: stat() failed on /etc/init.d/screen-cleanup, ignoring: No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, systemd, syslog

I got a virtual 18.04.1 (acting as apt-cacher-ng host) installation which shows the following repeating warning in it's syslog.

```
systemd-sysv-generator: stat() failed on /etc/init.d/screen-cleanup, ignoring: No such file or directory
```

It seems like `/etc/init.d/screen-cleanup` is a link to the not existing `/lib/init/upstart-job`.

How do i solve this issue? I do know i could filter the message in syslog, but this doesnt seem like the correct way how to handle it.

Any suggestions?

Side note: `screen` is installed and needed on that host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue, simply deleting the init file did the trick:

```
sudo rm /etc/init.d/screen-cleanup
```

Also see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429032/initctl-unable-to-connect-to-upstart

Comment: It belongs to the `screen` package. `sudo apt install --reinstall screen` will not touch it, but first removing it and then doing `sudo apt install --reinstall screen` will install a new version. So you should probably do that.